# Inserting docs quickly into Couchbase with actors

Tags: f#, actor, couchbase

I am writing a program which will put a lot of documents into a Couchbase store.  I'm using F# and I'm interested in the actor pattern as I feel this is a job that could be sped up greatly with actors.  What I'm unsure of is how I handle the Couchbase client with this.  I want to ensure that as many connections to Couchbase are available as possible but without causing any problems due to too many actors.  How do I go about instantiating clients or is there something that can take care of it for me?  I couldn't find any guides on the internet about people inserting docs into Couchbase with the actor pattern (doesn't have to be .NET).  Does anyone know of any good resources to start me off?

Comment: Does this help? [“Throttled” async download in F#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6219726/636019)

Comment: Definitely a start, I'm strugling to find information with f#, I guess because it's a much more recent language.  I'm not sure how I set the number of agents that can be spawned to process a mailbox and also what about instantiating a set number of couchbase clients, how can I inject a single instance (or fixed number of instances) of the couchbase client? I was also wondering from the couchbase side, how many connections can be made, or is this something to be experimented with?