# Concurrent Download with limited number of Workers and AsyncSeq from FSharpX (or ExtCore)

Tags: asynchronous, f#, computation-expression

I try a concurrent download with limited number of Workers using the AsyncSeq module.

Based on the FSharpX example of https://github.com/fsprojects/fsharpx/blob/master/samples/Crawler.fsx

```
let rec concurrentDownload concurrentWorkers download transform (urls:string list)  = 
    asyncSeq {
        let requests = BlockingQueueAgent<_>(1000)
        let results  = BlockingQueueAgent<_>(50)
        let worker() = async {
            while true do
                let!   url = requests.AsyncGet()
                let!   doc = download url
                match  doc with 
                | Some txt -> do! results.AsyncAdd( transform txt )
                | _        -> ()
            }
        // fill in all the requests
        for url in urls do
            do! requests.AsyncAdd url
        // create the workers and start them  
        for i in 1 .. concurrentWorkers do 
            worker() |> Async.Start
        // get the results and yield them in the asynchronous sequence
        while requests.Count > 0 && results.Count > 0 do 
            let!  res = results.AsyncGet()
            yield res 
    }

let rand  = new System.Random()
let rnd() = rand.Next(0,4000)

// a simulated download, sleep time depends on random number 
let download str = async { 
    let name = "dl " + str 
    let payload = rnd()
    printfn "Started : %s (payload=%d)" name payload
    do! Async.Sleep(1000 + payload)
    printfn "Finished: %s" name
    return Some name
    }

let urls = [1..10] |> List.map (sprintf "URL %d")
let concurrentWorkers = 5
let transform = id

let ret = concurrentDownload concurrentWorkers download transform urls
//ret // val it : AsyncSeq<string> = Microsoft.FSharp.Control.FSharpAsync`1[FSI_0012.FSharp.Control.AsyncSeqInner`1[System.String]]
let z =
    ret
    |> AsyncSeq.toBlockingSeq 
    |> Seq.toList
```

I assumed that z gets something like  seq ["dl URL 3"; "dl URL 5"; ... ]
because 'download' returns Some content.
The workers on the blocking queues working as expected:

```
Started : dl URL 1 (payload=2281)
Started : dl URL 3 (payload=741)
Started : dl URL 4 (payload=3283)
Started : dl URL 5 (payload=1117)
Started : dl URL 2 (payload=2435)
Finished: dl URL 3
Started : dl URL 6 (payload=263)
Finished: dl URL 5
Started : dl URL 7 (payload=1115)
Finished: dl URL 6
Started : dl URL 8 (payload=1041)
Finished: dl URL 1
Started : dl URL 9 (payload=959)
Finished: dl URL 2
Started : dl URL 10 (payload=604)
Finished: dl URL 7
Finished: dl URL 4
Finished: dl URL 10
Finished: dl URL 8
Finished: dl URL 9
```

The problem is, why is z an empty list? 
And not as exprected seq ["dl URL 3"; "dl URL 5"; ... ]?

As a reference, here is the toBlockingSeq function:

```
  // FSharpX AsyncSeq.toBlockingSeq   
  let toBlockingSeq (input : AsyncSeq<'T>) = 
    // Write all elements to a blocking buffer and then add None to denote end
    let buf = new BlockingQueueAgent<_>(1) 

    async {                 
      do! iterAsync   (Some >> buf.AsyncAdd) input  
      do! buf.AsyncAdd None 
    } |> Async.Start       

    // Read elements from the blocking buffer & return a sequences
    let rec loop () = 
      seq {
          match buf.Get() with
          | None   -> ()    
          | Some v -> 
              yield v       
              yield! loop() 
      }
    loop ()
```

Comment: I asked a similar question a few years ago. You might find something interesting in the answers [there](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6219726/11410).

Comment: Thank you Benjol for the link. It's a agent implicite state machine.
What I try is to build it with AsyncSeq because it's for me more composebale. Therefore easier to visualize.