# Any other examples of multi-state Agent programming in FSharp?

Tags: asynchronous, f#, agent, mailboxprocessor

I'm investigating F# agents that have multiple states, i.e., using the "let rec/and" keyword combination (per Expert F# 3.0's "Message Processing and State Machines") to provide multiple async blocks. The only example I've been able to find so far is the "throttling agent" discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219726/throttled-async-download-in-f)  (also Fssnip.net). Are there any other resources for learning this pattern?

edit: My specific application is an agent that has two states,

```
| StartFeed rateMultiplier replychannel ->

     - replychannel out data values at a delay (provided with each value) 
       multiplied by rateMultiplier
     - loop by using  
       thisAgent.Post(StartFeed rateMultiplier replychannel)


| Pause ->
```

I would like to provide some way to pass in a feed rate multiplier value that increases/decreases the delay by the passed-in multiplier in the "feed" async state, without interrupting the feed of values. I guess the question boils down to "how do you keep an async state block actively looping while still being aware of new messages?" Almost like skipping the inbox.Receive asynchronous wait, unless a message actually comes in? Inbox.scan?

edit 2: Given the message queue aspect of MailboxProcessor, I can see that an external message (with a different rateMultiplier value) that is received by the agent and placed in the queue will successfully change the rate without interrupting the flow of data values out. Any advice on the "Pause" would be still be appreciated.

Comment: got some 'Pause' and multi-state 'let rec / and" ideas from http://tryjoinads.org/docs/use/agents.html

Answer (score 0):

I have found Tomas Petricek's entry https://github.com/tpetricek/FSharp.AsyncExtensions/blob/master/src/Agents/BlockingQueueAgent.fs , which gives an agent, with the standard mailboxprocessor queue, a way to choose what async block it will employ to process the next incoming message (ie, let the agent 'change its state'):

- inbox.Receive() is used for the 'standard state' - the agent's message 'inbox' queue is neither full nor empty (State #1)
- inbox.Scan() is used for the 'edge' or limiting cases of empty (State #2) and full (State #3) message 'inbox' queue
- the actions the agent (in whichever of the three states) can take in response to received messages are written as **distinct async blocks that are given their *own* 'and' async block in the agent's 'let rec' loop; I had thought that 'let rec...and...' async blocks were restricted to having a message receipt function (.Receive, .Scan, etc), which is incorrect, they may be any async block that maintains the desired control flow, as seen in the next feature of the 'let rec...and...' agent body:
- once the agent, in whichever of the 3 states, responds to a new message by routing to the appropriate action, the action is itself finished with a call to another 'and' async block of the agent body 'let rec' loop, a 'chooseState()', an if/then block that determines which state will handle a new message and calls  that 'and' async block from among the 3 available.

This example seems **essential** in demonstrating **idiomatic** use of the multi-state agent body construction, specifically how to combine the three functions of message receipt, response, and looping control as mutually recursive elements of a single 'let rec...and...and..." construction.

Of course other message-passing frameworks exist, but this is a general logic/routing design for a more complex agent, whatever the framework, so:
thanks, Tomas.