# Keep running a specific number of tasks

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, task

I have been trying to do this:

Create 'N' Task to execute and keep running this number of taks for a period of time, in that case
the one task finalize, then i should start a new task  to keep the same number of task.

I dont know if is this possible to handle with TaskScheduler or  i have to create a custom TaskScheduler.

Another option i think could work is , use TPL DataFlow Producer-Consumer when the task finish then taskscheduler take a new task generate by producer.

The question is: how can i  create a new task when one finished to keep the same number of tasks?

Comment: And the question is....?

Comment: TPL DataFlow's `ActionBlock` can have a defined degree of paralleism.  Meaning, if you want 5 tasks running at once... and then once one finishes, it will grab the next available task to run that.

Comment: It sounds like you're misusing Tasks.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yeah, maybe i could use on the wrong way tasks, but i dont want use threads, My accomplish is to stress a one server create a N requests, but i should keep 'running' a specific numbers of request for a period of time.

Comment: Look into Parallel.ForEach and PLINQ. That's likely to trivially solve your problem.

Comment: Doesn't threadpool do this?  Set a max number for the threadpool and have at it.  Except a thread and a task are different...

Comment: So make N tasks, and put an infinite loop in each one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This code will keep running `numTasks` Tasks in parallel.

```
int numTasks = 5;
SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(numTasks);
while(true)
{
    semaphore.Wait();
    Task.Run(() =>
        {
            DoSomething();
        })
        .ContinueWith(_ => semaphore.Release());
}
```

Comment: I love this idea, but how could you do this with asynchronous tasks?

Answer (score 0):

Task scheduler could be used to run an executable that you could use to perform a set of work/tasks. Alternatively, you could simply create a windows service...